# How to filter array in php using array_search value less than

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have following array in php which I am trying to filter on the date. Date is stored as "Ymd" format in DropDate key.

I would like to apply filter where Dropdate < 20171102 so it only shows me 1 record.

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(30) {
        ["Id"]=>
        int(18762)
        ["DropDate"]=>
        string(8) "20171101"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(30) {
        ["Id"]=>
        int(18760)
        ["DropDate"]=>
        string(8) "20171102"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(30) {
        ["Id"]=>
        int(18258)
        ["DropDate"]=>
        string(8) "20171102"
    }
}
```

I have used the following code but it adds [{0:"Id":18280,"...] when I json_encode it.

```
$records = array_filter($bookings, function($value) {
        $todays_date = date('Ymd');
        return $value['DropDate'] < (int)$todays_date;
    });
```

I am not sure how I can do an array_search on less than value for dropdate field.

```
$todays_date = date('Ymd');
    if(($key = array_search($todays_date, array_column($student,'DropDate'))) !== false) {
        unset($student[$key]);
    }
```

Then when I do json_encode to return it to my app I get strange behaviour like it adds 0 and 1 infront of each object.

```
 [{"0":{"Id":18280,"DropDate":"20171030"},"1":{"Id":18284,"DropDate":"20171101"}}]
```

My application expects this with no 0 or 1

```
 [{"Id":18280,"DropDate":"20171030"},{"Id":18284,"DropDate":"20171101"}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, as far as I can tell, it gives you the required record. If you just want the date, you can use `array_map` to modify the resulting structure.

Comment: it seems that in your array, `DropDate` is a string, you should maybe convert it to integer before testing in `return $value['DropDate'] < (int)$todays_date;`, maybe you have inconsistent results because of that?

Comment: Thank you , I should have mentioned that when I json_encode the filtered array I get [{"0":{"Id":18280,"DropDate":"20171030"},"1":{"Id":18284,"DropDate":"20171101"}}]  what my application expects is [{"Id":18280,"DropDate":"20171030"},"1":{"Id":18284,"DropDate":"20171101"}]

Comment: @snowflakes74 your expected array still has a `"1": ` is this what you actually want, or a typo?

Comment: No sorry it is a typo I have just now fixed it. Thank you

Comment: call `$arr = array_values($arr);` before json_encode

Comment: Thank you @splash58 that did it!!

Comment: json_encode "save" indexes if they are not starting from zero or having non sequence integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is the right way to go.

<sup>Note: Comparing two date strings will work just as well as comparing two timestamps, but IMHO it's better to use timestamps.</sup>

Try this:

```
$records = array_filter($bookings, function ($row) {
    return $row['DropDate'] < date('Ymd');
});

echo json_encode($records);
```

Output:

```
[{"Id":18762,"DropDate":"20171101"}]
```

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/891574)

Comment: it is always better IMO to work with timestamps, but it's not really needed in this particular case: this format of date works allright for numerical comparison but it just **needs to be converted to int before**. In his case, it may be useful because it offers a comparison by date, which don't if you use timestamps (comparison is by seconds or milliseconds)

Comment: @Kaddath Turns out that casting to an int is actually completely unnecessary: https://eval.in/891571

Comment: @Kaddath Both statements return false as expected, see [here](https://eval.in/891582)

Comment: my bad, i was thinking about javascript as written in the comment :D yes PHP is more clever in this case

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this using the powerful `DateTime` along with `array_filter`:

```
<?php
$bookings = [
  ['Id' => 18762, 'DropDate' => '20171101'],
  ['Id' => 18760, 'DropDate' => '20171102'],
  ['Id' => 18258, 'DropDate' => '20171102'],
];

$records = array_filter($bookings, function ($row) {
  $today = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', date('Y-m-d'))->format('U');
  $booking_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $row['DropDate'])->format('U');
  return $booking_date < $today;
});

print_r($records);
```

This gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 18762
            [DropDate] => 20171101
        )

)
```

Nicer to work with timestamps. Hope this helps.

Demo: https://eval.in/891570

---

Regarding the JSON stuff at the end of the question

```
$input = <<<JSON
[{"0":{"Id":18280,"DropDate":"20171030"},"1":{"Id":18284,"DropDate":"20171101"}}] 
JSON;
```

You can decode from your source like:

```
$decoded = json_decode($input, true);
$bookings = array_values($decoded[0]);
```

And then use the above code.

Demo for this: https://eval.in/891591

Comment: Thank you that's brilliant. Please see my updated question regarding when json_encode it adds 0 and 1 infron of it. I know I should have mentioned in my question before